# Using KissFFT on a wave file

Tags: c, fft, wav, libsndfile, kissfft

I am trying to use the [KissFFT Library](http://kissfft.sourceforge.net/) with [this 11 second 44kHz .wav sample file](http://www.beis.de/Elektronik/FreqResp/WAV/MSin44W16-13.WAV) as a test input.

However as I process the file with a window size of 512, I am getting only 1 output value. Which is weird, the 11 sec .wav file at 44kHz should not give 1 value as an output with a windows size of 512. A smaller windows like 16 would give me 5 values, which is still a low count.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "kiss_fft.h"

#define WIN 512

int main()
{
    char *music_file = "C:/MSin44W16-13.wav";
    FILE *in;
    char buf[WIN * 2];
    int nfft = WIN, i, fx;
    double intensity = 0;
    kiss_fft_cfg cfg;
    kiss_fft_cpx cx_in[WIN];
    kiss_fft_cpx cx_out[WIN];
    short *sh;

    cfg = kiss_fft_alloc(nfft, 0, 0, 0);
    in = fopen(music_file, "r");
    if (!in) {
        printf("unable to open file: %s\n", music_file);
        perror("Error");
        return 1;
    }
    fx = 0;
    while (fread(buf, 1, WIN * 2, in)) 
    {
        for (i = 0;i<WIN;i++) {
            sh = (short *)&buf[i * 2];
            cx_in[i].r = (float) (((double)*sh) / 32768.0);
            cx_in[i].i = 0.0;
        }

        kiss_fft(cfg, cx_in, cx_out);
        //Display the value of a position
        int position = 511;
        intensity = sqrt(pow(cx_out[position].r, 2) + pow(cx_out[position].i, 2));
        printf("%9.4f\n", intensity);

        //Display all values
        /*
        for (i = 0;i<WIN;i++) {
            //printf("Joe: cx_out[i].r:%f\n", cx_out[i].r);
            //printf("Joe: cx_out[i].i:%f\n", cx_out[i].i);
            intensity = sqrt(pow(cx_out[i].r,2) + pow(cx_out[i].i,2));
            printf("%d - %9.4f\n", i, intensity);
        }
        */

    }
    free(cfg);
    scanf("%d");

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
 42.7577
```

---

This is the Updated Code version, but I am getting errors at compile:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "kiss_fft.h"
#include "sndfile.h"

#define WIN 512

int main()
{
    char *music_file = "C:/voice.wav";
    SNDFILE *infile;
    SF_INFO      sfinfo;
    //int          readcount;

    short buf[WIN * 2];
    int nfft = WIN;
    double intensity = 0;
    kiss_fft_cfg cfg;
    kiss_fft_cpx cx_in[WIN];
    kiss_fft_cpx cx_out[WIN];
    short *sh;

    cfg = kiss_fft_alloc(nfft, 0, 0, 0);


    if (!( infile = sf_open(music_file, SFM_READ, &sfinfo) ))
    {   /* Open failed so print an error message. */
        printf("Not able to open input file %s.\n", "input.wav");
        /* Print the error message fron libsndfile. */
        sf_perror(NULL);
        return  1;
    }

    while ((sf_read_short(infile, buf, WIN)))//fread(buf, 1, WIN * 2, in)
    {
        //system("cls");

        for (int i = 0;i<WIN;i++) {
            sh = (short *)&buf[i * 2];
            cx_in[i].r = (float) (((double)*sh) / 32768.0);
            cx_in[i].i = 0.0;
        }

        kiss_fft(cfg, cx_in, cx_out);
        //Display the value of a position
        int position = 511;
        intensity = sqrt(pow(cx_out[position].r, 2) + pow(cx_out[position].i, 2));
        printf("%9.4f\n", intensity);

        //Display all values
        /*
        for (i = 0;i<WIN;i++) {
            //printf("Joe: cx_out[i].r:%f\n", cx_out[i].r);
            //printf("Joe: cx_out[i].i:%f\n", cx_out[i].i);
            intensity = sqrt(pow(cx_out[i].r,2) + pow(cx_out[i].i,2));
            printf("%d - %9.4f\n", i, intensity);
        }
        */

    }
    sf_close(infile);
    free(cfg);
    int temp;
    scanf_s("%d", &temp);

    return 0;
}
```

I followed the steps on this post:

["error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" error in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276399/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error-in-visual-studio-2010)

And I still get these errors:

[image]

Comment: Solved it, I had to add at the top of my code:
#pragma comment(lib, "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mega-Nerd/libsndfile/lib/libsndfile-1.lib")
then did this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672025/trying-to-add-reference-to-project-in-visual-studio-2012-no-items-found


then did that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767820/visual-studio-2010-dll-missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem does not comes from KissFFT, but rather from the fact that you are trying to read a *binary* wave file opened in ASCII mode on the line:

```
in = fopen(music_file, "r");
```

As you later try to read data with `fread` you eventually hit an invalid character. In your specific sample file, the 215<sup>th</sup> character read is the [Substitute Character (hex value `0x1A`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character), which is interpreted as an end of file marker by your C runtime library. Correspondingly, [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) stops filling in more data and eventually return 0 (at the second iteration with `WIN` set to 512 and a little later with `WIN` set to 16).

To get around this problem, you should open the file in binary more with:

```
in = fopen(music_file, "rb");
```

Note that this will ensure the binary data is read as-is into your input buffer, but would not decode the wave file header for you. To properly read and decode a wave file and get meaningful data in, you should look into using an audio library (such as [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) to name one). If you must roll your own wave file reader you should read the [specifications](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/wave.html) and/or check out one of many tutorials on the topic.

Comment: Ok,  I am trying your solution to use the libsndfile. If I got this straight my solution would work for a raw file, but since the wave file has a header, I need to use the libsndfile to get usable results?

I tried adding the library to my project, but I am missing one small piece of code.

What do I replace this line with:
`while (fread(buf, 1, WIN * 2, in))` ?

This is what I have so far:
`char *music_file = "C:/voice.wav";
 SNDFILE *infile;
 SF_INFO      sfinfo;
 int          readcount;

infile = sf_open_read(music_file, &sfinfo);`

Comment: Yes. Try `while (sf_read_short(infile, buf, WIN))` for a single channel wav file (number of channels would be obtained from `sfinfo` filled with wav file header information by the `sf_open_read` call).

Comment: I tried it but it is not working, I updated the main post to show the errors I got

Comment: you need to 1) change `sf_open_read` to `sf_open(music_file, SFM_READ, &sfinfo)` 2) include `libsndfile-1.lib` as an input library in VS. It would also be a good idea to clear the remaining warnings such as the one about `sscanf`

Comment: I cleared the other warning, but how can I include the libsndfile-1.lib as an input library in VS?
If you mean add it to the VC++ directories, i already did

Comment: Have a look at [How to fix unresolved external symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2994596), and in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/2994596).

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same errors, I even tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276399/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error-in-visual-studio-2010